# How can I tell if Heroku is sending gzipped responses?

Tags: http, compression, gzip, nsurlconnection, websocket

I'm making an iPhone application that requests JSON from Heroku.

1. Am I getting a gzipped response?
   And, does the iPhone automatically
   unzip gzipped responses, or do you
   have to program that in? I'm using
   `NSURLConnection` asynchronously
   (with the delegate protocol) as
   described in the Xcode docs.

   When I do:

   ```
   curl -I http://acani.heroku.com/users/4c96ee4f1467281352000049/1234/50/50
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Server: nginx/0.7.67
   Date: Sun, 17 Oct 2010 16:27:25 GMT
   Content-Type: application/json
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Length: 11532
   X-Varnish: 2314841869
   Age: 0
   Via: 1.1 varnish
   ```
2. I'm also using the Zimt WebSocket code with AsyncSocket for chat. The chat server is Node.js. Should I be gzipping each chat message? Or is that done automatically?
3. I wonder, to reduce bandwidth, does Twitter gzip your tweets (with JavaScript on the web, or Objective-C on the iPhone) before they are sent to Twitter?

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 4):

To detect if a response is compressed or not, you need to look for a `Content-Encoding` header.  It can be set to either `gzip`, `compress`, or `deflate`.  See [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) Section 3.5 for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. Now, how do I tell heroku to gzip for Sinatra?

Comment: An HTTP server is not allowed to compress a response unless the client's request indicates that compression is supported.  This is done via the `Accept-Encoding` request header, which specifies a comma-separated list of encodings that the client recognizes.  The server can then pick one of them and specify in the `Content-Encoding` response header.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use RFС for any standard related constants. I want to recommend using [iana registries](https://www.iana.org/protocols) instead. If you need `Content-Encoding` than you can use [http-parameters.xml](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xml).

HTTP Content Coding Registry:

```
aes128gcm
br
compress
deflate
exi
gzip
identity
pack200-gzip
x-compress
x-gzip
zstd
```

You can do even better solution:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

torsocks wget \
  --recursive \
  --domains "iana.org" \
  --no-parent "https://www.iana.org/protocols" \
  --accept-regex "https://www.iana.org/(assignments|protocols)/.*"
```

```sh
git init
./download.sh
git add . && git commit
```

Do you need to find any constants from standards? Just grep `iana` folder.
Do you need to be familiar with all recent changes? `download.sh && git diff`.